# mapbox+three.js raycaster don't intersect with any object3D

Tags: three.js, mapbox

My English may be not the best because I'm from China.

I use mapbox+three.js, and borrowed from the Camera logic in `Threebox`.

I want to test whether a line passes through an Object3D.

I know the start position of line, the end position of line and the position of Object3D.

and I add a `arrowHelper` for the raycaster. the direction is right.

the `material.side` is Already set Double.

But there is no intersects.

This is the part of the code.

```
const direction = endPosition.clone().sub(startPosition.clone()).normalize();

const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(startPosition, direction)

const arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
      raycaster.ray.direction,
      raycaster.ray.origin,
      1,
      '#000',
    );

const intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(object, true);
```

this is the effect picture:
[image]

Strangely. I use the raycaster with the mouse and the Camera is right. like this

```
this.raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, this.camera);
```

How do I change the code？